# How to make the horizontal srcollbar of web broswer contol right to left

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a web browser control in my C# project and its text contents is written in a right-to-left language.

So I want the horizontal scroll bar of the web browser to start from right to left instead of left to right.

There is no right to left property for the web browser control.

Comment: i dont understand why there is a downvote

Comment: I don't know too, but maybe because of "Thanks" or "Please tell me".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402428/textbox-with-vertical-scrollbar-on-the-left-side

Comment: aria u mean being polite here causes me a negative vote ? , jesus

Comment: @ J.steen i dont think there is a dublicate there

Comment: @YekiDige "Please", "hello" etc. [aren't necessary](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) and even frowned upon since these things do not improve the quality of the question.

Comment: I am new here ( signed up  today) , question edited , that negative vote was not fair